# Aperiodic Table of Alien Elements

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, pattern, visual

Yes, yes, aliens again...

[image: the question]

... so, what is the next row in this aperiodic table of alien elements?

(To save you from drawing and uploading an image to answer the question, 25 possibilities follow. 5 are the elements in question, and the other 20 are not elements. Which 5, and in what order? I put a spoiler tag on them since they are a minor hint, you may wish to try to answer the question without looking at them.)

> [image: possible answers]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> D4, A4, C4, C3, A2

Explained:

> Each element represents the prime numbers. For example, the top-left one represents 2, the next represents 3, etc.
>
>  To calculate the representation for a given prime number, subtract 1 and find the prime factorisation of that number. Then take the representations of those factors and put them inside the circle.
>
>  26th prime is 101: 101 - 1 = 100 = 2 * 2 * 5 * 5 = D4
>  27th prime is 103: 103 - 1 = 102 = 2 * 3 * 17 = A4
>  28th prime is 107: 107 - 1 = 106 = 2 * 53 = C4
>  29th prime is 109: 109 - 1 = 108 = 2 * 2 * 3 * 3 * 3 = C3
>  30th prime is 113: 113 - 1 = 112 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 7 = A2

[and here's the picture --OP]

> [image: D4 A4 C4 C3 A2]

Comment: Well done, and welcome!